# Why can't magento accept `content` as a database field name?

Tags: magento-1.7, adminhtml

I am creating a new module and in that module I add a form which has a field name `content` in the database.

Now when I add a wyswig editor in this form with the field name `content` in the database, the layout of the form in the backend changes completely as compared to default layout.

But when I changed the database field name from `content` to any other name lets say `content_html` or `content_h` etc etc., the layout of the form now appeared as a default form.

This happens only when I use wyswig editor, and without wyswig if I create simple form it accepts the values in the database under the `content` field name.

Why can't magento accept the `content` as a field name, using wyswig editor.

Comment: I assume this has something to do with tinymce stripping tag. But why it would only do it when something is named "content" is beyond me. Have a look at http://alanstorm.com/magento_html5_tinymce for some more info

Comment: Justus Krapp gives the thought [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21753693/why-cant-magento-accept-content-as-a-database-field-name) but still I didn't understand properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just so this will have an answer....
Based on the [post mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21816327/2047249).

You cannot have a field named `content` because, in this case magento creates the following textarea

```
<textarea name="content" id="content"...></textarea>
```

Now comes the tinymce js that tries to turn your textarea into a WYSIWYG editor. It looks for the element with id `content`, but this element already exists higher in the DOM.

```
<div class="main-col" id="content">
```

This causes an malfunction.

So basically the problem is not that your element (or table column) has the name `content`. The problem is that the id of the element is `content`.

Magento actually has an entity with a field name `content` and works just fine. It is Cms page entity.

Take a look at `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Cms_Page_Edit_Tab_Content::_prepareForm`. You will see this:

```
$contentField = $fieldset->addField('content', 'editor', array(
    'name'      => 'content',
    'style'     => 'height:36em;',
    'required'  => true,
    'disabled'  => $isElementDisabled,
    'config'    => $wysiwygConfig
));
```

The solution is to have a different id for the textarea.
In order to achieve this you can use

```
$form->setHtmlIdPrefix('some_prefix_');
```

This transforms all the ids for the elements in the form from `elemId` to `some_prefix_ememId`.

In your case `content` becomes `some_prefix_content` and everything should work.

Comment: and discard my draft answer :)

Comment: @Marius thanks for giving the details. It really help me to understood this.